Mean of a Function: Limit
Let the mean of a function $f(x)$ over the interval $(a,b)$ be defined as:
$\bar{f}=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$.
Is there something such as:
$\bar{f}=\displaystyle{\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}}\frac{\epsilon}{b-a}\int_{\frac{a}{\epsilon}}^{\frac{b}{\epsilon}}f(x)dx$
?
If so, where can I read more about it?

What if $f$ is positive unbounded function and $a$ is negative and $b$ is positive?

If the function is uniform (i.e. constant) over the real line $\mathbb{R}$, then this is correct, otherwise it depends on the behavior of the function over the real line and $[a, b]$. I think you can say that this is true if the function is periodic and symmetric along the y axis. This question is very general and depends on the behavior of the function along the real line, whether it is a probability distribution function, etc. I'd suggest looking at a signals and systems (Ulaby and Yagle) book's first chapters.
